# How to get hash in a given array list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My Ruby question is in a given array of non-empty strings, create and return a hash as follows: for each string add its first character as a key with its last character as a value in defn method

```
def pairs1(arry)
    arry = [ "code", "bug"]
    final_hash = {}
    pairs1.each do |var|
    final_hash[] = puts var[0] puts var[-1]
    final_hash[var[0]] = var[-1]
end
puts final_hash
```

The error I got is :

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...final_hash[] = puts var[0] puts var[-1]
...                           ^~
```

Comment: error is telling you clearly that you forgot `end` on the end of you method

Comment: `final_hash[] = puts var[0] puts var[-1]` why you have `puts` here?

Comment: When asking questions, you usually want to add the expected output of the method for the example you provided :)

Comment: This is too low level question. You have missed lots of basic so I would like to suggest you to go through basic again and do not run those topics fast without giving practical trial.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code:

```
def pairs1(arry)
  arry = [ "code", "bug"]
  final_hash = {}
  pairs1.each do |var|
    final_hash[] = puts var[0] puts var[-1]
    final_hash[var[0]] = var[-1]
  end
  puts final_hash
```

A few things are a bit off. You should remove the array initialization (`arry = [...]`) because you're passing in a array through the parameters of the method already. If you keep it like this, passing a parameter won't have any effect on the method. Also this line `final_hash[] = puts var[0] puts var[-1]` doesn't do anything (aside from raising an error), so you can remove it too. You also want to call the `#each` methon on the array, calling it on the method itself doesn't make much sense here. If you also add an `end` to the end of the method you get a working version of your method:

```
  def pairs1(arry)
    final_hash = {}
    arry.each do |var|
      final_hash[var[0]] = var[-1]
    end
    puts final_hash
  end
```

Keep in mind, this method currently doesn't return the value of `final_hash`, it just prints the value to the console and returns `nil`. If you want to change that just remove the `puts` from the last line.

You can also do something like this:

```
arry = [ "code", "bug"]

def pairs1(arry)
  arry.each_with_object({}) { |element,hash| hash[element[0]] = element[-1] }
end

pairs1(arry)
# => {"c"=>"e", "b"=>"g"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `end` to the close defining of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inject` method too. And for readability I prefer `chars.first` and `chars.last`

```rb
arry = ['code', 'bug']
final_hash = arry.inject({}) do |memo, val|
  memo[val.chars.first] = val[val.chars.last]
  memo
end
p final_hash
{"c"=>"e", "b"=>"g"}
```

Comment: If you use `each_with_object` you can lose the trailing `memo` :) Also, what's the performance hit of converting to an array and grabbing first / last as opposed to getting these straight from the string? Don't get me wrong, this is a good answer, just a couple of things that jumped out at me.

Comment: I dont think this is a good question at all, that can help anybody) And you are right, chars.first is not good for performance) Just as option.